# Show that $f\left( \bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}A_\alpha\right) \subset \bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}fA_\alpha$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: X \to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty and let $\{A_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \mathcal{A} \} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$. Show that $$f\left( \bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}A_\alpha\right) \subset \bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}fA_\alpha$$

I'm stuck on how to prove this. If I take some $y \in f\left( \bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}A_\alpha\right)$, then there must exist $x \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}A_\alpha$, but this means that $x$ is in every $A_\alpha$ regardless of what $\alpha$ is right? I don't see how this is of help here?

Comment: If $x$ is in every $A_\alpha$, then $f(x)$ is in every $f(A_\alpha)$.

Comment: So $y=f(x)\in A_\alpha\forall\alpha\in\mathcal A$ and thus $y\in\cap_{\alpha\in\mathcal A}f(A_\alpha)$.